# Using XSL to list all fields of an item in Sitecore CMS

Tags: content-management-system, xslt, field, sitecore

I am using a debug device in sitecore (6) that will output a 'developer' view of a page when the url is appended with a certain query string (which activates the device). On the page, I have item name, template, branch master, workflow info etc.

I would like to list all the fields on the item using the xsl render - preferably not including the hidden (__) fields, but doesn't matter if they are there.

I have tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$sc_item/fields/field">
```

but this only lists five fields for each item:

- __created
- __revision
- __updated
- __updated by
- __lock

The sitecore docs say use the sc functionality to access field *values*, but I need to get the field *names* first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have realized the answer: empty fields are not listed in the item XML!